# SQL constraint “at least one of two attributes”

Tags: sql, constraints

I need to create a table `User` with `telephone_number` and `e_mail_adress` columns. Each row must have at least one of those columns set. It could have both or just one, but it must have at least one of them.

How can I express that constraint in SQL?

Comment: What database engine are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create table Users (
  /* Whatever */
  TelephoneNumber varchar(2000) null,
  EmailAddress varchar(5) null,
  constraint CK_AtLeastOneContact CHECK (
    TelephoneNumber is not null or
    EmailAddress is not null
  )
)
```

You may want to adjust the data types :-)